# Math proof required (Probability)

Tags: probability-theory

From
Pr[E] = Pr[E|A].Pr[A] + Pr[E|A'].Pr[A']

how can we prove
Pr[E] <= Pr[E|A] + Pr[A']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pr[E] <= Pr[E|A] + Pr[A']
```

the left side can be replaced with the first line..

```
Pr[E|A].Pr[A] + Pr[E|A'].Pr[A'] <= Pr[E|A] + Pr[A']
```

hmm so lets subtract "Pr[E|A].Pr[A]" on both sides.
On the right side, you can translate Pr[E|A] = Pr[E|A]*1 = Pr[E|A] (Pr[A] + Pr[A'])

```
Pr[E|A'].Pr[A'] <= Pr[E|A].Pr[A'] + Pr[A']
```

now we can put both sides into brackets in order to isolate Pr[A']

```
( Pr[E|A'] ) * Pr[A'] <= ( Pr[E|A] + 1 ) * Pr[A']
```

and divide by Pr[A']

```
Pr[E|A'] <= Pr[E|A] + 1
```

so.. if..
Pr[E|A] = 0 
then both sides can be equal (if left side is 1)
in all other cases the right side is larger, since it is more than 1, and left side can maximum be 1

Answer (score 0):

Pr[E] <= Pr[E|A] is satisfied if Pr[E] is a subset of Pr[E|A]. This is proven with:
Pr[E|A] = Pr[E] + Pr[A] - Pr[E&A].

So given any probability E and A, Pr[E] remains a subset of Pr[E|A].

Comment: I understand that it is satisfied if PR[E]is a subset of Pr[E|A], but I think Pr[E|A] is not defined as Pr[E] + Pr[A], or did I understand something wrong? If chance for E and chance for A is more than 50% each, then still.. Pr[E|A] cannot be more than 100%

Comment: Pr[E|A] = Pr[E] + Pr[A] - Pr[E&A] looks for me like Pr(A conjunged B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A cut with B), But the Pr[A|B] is meant as Pr[A] under the condition that event B has occured, or is it an 'or'-connection?